# Unable to trim data upto 3 decimals points from pandas dataframe using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below

```
[8.01427, 47.0002]
[8.01427, 47.0002]
[8.01427, 47.0002]
[8.01427, 47.0002]
[8.01427, 47.0002]
```

Expected Output

```
8.014:47.000
8.014:47.000
8.014:47.000
```

My code

```
def func(y,n):
    if y < 0 :
      return "%0.2f" % (-(y * 10 ** n // -1 / 10 ** n))
    else :
      return "%0.2f" % (y * 10 ** n // 1 / 10 ** n)

DataF.loc[:, ('param')] = DataF['geo'].apply (lambda x: ':'.join ( [func ( y, 3 ) for y in x] ) )
```

Error

> '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: What is `func` in your code? Is your data string type, or list of floats, or list of strings?

Comment: @QuangHoang, added `func` in the question

Comment: @QuangHoang its  dtype('O')

Comment: There's your problem: `if y < 0`, your data seems to be strings, not numerical type.

Comment: @QuangHoang, how to fix that

Comment: @QuangHoang, I tried `to numeric` not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `'geo'` column seems to contains strings `'[8.01427,47.0002']'`. Let's try:

```
DataF['param'] = DataF['geo'].str.replace('(\[)(\d+\.\d{,3})\d*, (\d+\.\d{,3})\d*(\])',
                                          r'\2:\3')
```

Output:

```
                  geo         param
0  [8.01427, 47.0002]  8.014:47.000
1  [8.01427, 47.0002]  8.014:47.000
2  [8.01427, 47.0002]  8.014:47.000
3  [8.01427, 47.0002]  8.014:47.000
4  [8.01427, 47.0002]  8.014:47.000
```